# OTP S/KEY One Time password - Folding MD5 Digest output

Tags: java-me, one-time-password

Im trying to create a one time password generator for a phone. In the RFC2289 it specifies that i must fold the output of the MD5, i'm using bouncy castle MD5 and i cant work out how to fold the byte array output.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    md5[i] ^= md5[i+8];
}
```

This is what i have so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you want this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    md5[i] ^= md5[i + 8];
return Arrays.copyOf(md5, 8);
```

This way, only the first 64 bits (which are used by OTP) is returned.